# Stop SSIS package after running locally

Tags: vb.net, ssis

In dire need of help. I have a simple SSIS package created but here is the thing. It is NOT stored nor ran from the SQL Server Agent. It's stored locally. We don't have access to utilize SQL Server Agent. So we are using a batch file that is scheduled in Windows to execute the SSIS package. This works, however, someone has to press the stop button when finished. I've googled how to stop it through vb.net but everything I've read is based on hitting the SQL server, looking for the package name and then stopping it this way. Since this isn't stored in SQL Server, that method doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly are you running this package?  Manually, via code, application, etc?

Comment: Not sure I understand this completely, when scheduled through `Windows Scheduler` the `SSIS` package would automatically run and take whatever the time it takes to complete. From where do you have the "Stop button" appearing.

Comment: Even though the package isn't stored in SQL Server, it still has to RUN on a SQL Server, and that server is where you would stop the running package.

Comment: Stopping a running package could cause problems if it does not stop where you desire.  Perhaps a workaround is to create a second to final task that creates a condition that would then be checked for with a C# script task that could then halt the package.  Take a look at the following link for that code, but also keep any eye on whether the package is still be held in memory after it is stopped.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.runningpackage.stop?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_RunningPackage_Stop